# Macro envío Correo con Distinta Cuenta

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Tengo una macro que a través de un botón manda el correo con mensaje, asunto, para y archivo adjunto. Toma la aplicación de Outlook para enviarlo; funciona perfectamente, el tema es que Outlook contiene dos cuentas de correo, una predeterminada y la otra para elegir. Lo que intento es forzar para que el mensaje salga de una cuenta en especifico, busque un código el cual adapte pero continua sin enviarlo de la cuenta que se requiere. La suite el Office 365

El código es el siguiente:

```
Sub ENVIO_CORREO()

Dim PARA As String
Dim ARCHIVO As String
Dim TITULO As String
Dim MENSAJE As String

Dim Aplicación As Outlook.Application
Dim Correo As Outlook.MailItem
Set Aplicación = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set Correo = Aplicación.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Cuenta = ObtenerCuenta(Aplicación, "direccioncomercial@correo.com.mx")

Range("A150").Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
A = ActiveCell.Row

For i = 2 To A
    
    TITULO = Cells(i, 1).Value
    ARCHIVO = Cells(i, 4).Value
    PARA = Cells(i, 3).Value
    MENSAJE = Cells(i, 5).Value
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    With Correo
        .to = PARA
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = TITULO
        .Body = MENSAJE
        .Attachments.Add "X:\Proyectos\Vector ETFs\" & ARCHIVO
        .SendUsingAccount = Aplicación.Session.Accounts.Item(Cuenta)
        .Display
        .Send
    End With
Next i

End Sub

Function ObtenerCuenta(Aplicación As Object, EmailAddress As String)
For Each oAccount In Aplicación.Session.Accounts
    If oAccount.AccountType = olPop3 And _
       oAccount.SmtpAddress = EmailAddress Then
       ObtenerCuenta = oAccount
       Exit For
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Alguno sabrá que debo hacer? Gracias

Comment: mirate esto: [Propiedad MailItem.Sender (Outlook)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sender)

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del bloque `With Correo` debes añadir esta propiedad: `.SentOnBehalfOfName = "direccion@dominio"`